# calendar extender controls in Gridview causes unnecessary postback

Tags: asp.net, datepicker, calendar, postback, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In the following code I receive unnecessary post back if i use Calendar extender control along with a textbox in a Gridview. This means that in the following code when runs **UpdateEmployeeInAppForm**  is called twice. Outside Gridview it works fine. Can Any body help me ?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemType="Employee">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table> <tr>
                                <td>Date Of Birth</td>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbDOB" runat="server" OnTextChanged="UpdateEmployeeInAppForm" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%# Item.DOB%>'></asp:TextBox>

                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="tbDOB_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Format="dd MMMM yyyy" SelectedDate='<%# Item.DOB%>'
                                        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="tbDOB" ></asp:CalendarExtender>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
</table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

```
                              <asp:TextBox ID="tbDOB" runat="server" OnTextChanged="UpdateEmployeeInAppForm"  AutoPostBack="true" 
                                        Text='<%#Item.DOB.HasValue ? Item.DOB.Value.Date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy") : "" %>'></asp:TextBox>                                        
                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="tbDOB_CalendarExtender" runat="server"   Format="dd MMMM yyyy"                                           
                                        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="tbDOB" ></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Remove **SelectedDate='<%# Item.DOB%>'** from the Calendar extender control and make the format in the textbox and calendar same.